# Send M365 meeting invitations to selected attendees

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft365

I don't think I can do what I want, but thought I'd check here before giving up.  I'm using EWS (direct) to create a meeting for a M365 user. There is an attendee list, plus a resource attendee (e.g. a room).  When I use CreateItem, I can specify "SendMeetingInvitations" as SendToNone, or SendOnlyToAll. The latter option sends invitations to all attendees.  But what I want is to send the invitation just to the resource, not normal users.  Any way I can do that?  Or is there some other way that I can reserve a block of time for a resource, i.e. write directly to the resource calendar?